# emacs ubuntu dependency issue

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install "gettext" package in Ubuntu 16.04, and it was interrupted in the middle. Since then, I have been getting the following errors whenever I run a `sudo apt-get install` command.

> dpkg: error processing package emacs (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
>   Errors were encountered while processing: emacs24 emacs

I tried to the broken package fixer available in the synaptic manager, and also tried executing `sudo apt-get -f install`. I also tried re-installing the `emacs24` library, but ended up with the same error.

Can anyone assist me in fixing this issue?.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message from the failed installation would be required to troubleshoot this. Not a programming question anyway; voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to re-install `emacs24`, try doing this:

```
sudo apt-get purge emacs24  #removes configuration files as well
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Please find below the error message I get. What do you think must have happend?. Any help is appreciated.                   `emacs24: error while loading shared libraries: libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: install script from emacsen-common package failed
dpkg: error processing package emacs24-lucid (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: emacs24-lucid.`

Comment: @userDtrm Is this the entire error message? If not, you should update your question with the entire text of the error, it might help to diagnose.

Comment: I had to purge all emacs related libraries which in the end resulted in fixing up of the issues. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.